# How to create items in paypal for in app purchase

Tags: paypal, in-app-purchase

I am building an in app purchase shop for my companies pc game.
I know that in android and ios you create the items in your developer account and then buy them through there.
Is there a way to do something similiar in Paypal?
P.S. I have already developed the connection with paypal's rest api and am able to charge users through paypal. But Instead of passing the price of the item and it's description etc.. to paypal I would rather pass an item code and have paypal show the user the correct price in his currency. Plus I want to be able to pull this data from paypal and display it to the user from there.
My server is gamesparks which works with a node.js and mongo db.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does not offer anything like what you're wanting. You can pass through the item_name variable so that the order invoices show the item name, but you can't set up any items with prices/description. Usually that process is taken on by the developer on the project side, not processor side.

The most effective and safest way to retrieve information for PayPal payments is to set up an IPN. Here is the documentation if you are unaware. 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/